# C finding out if a value exists in a linkedlist

Tags: c, list, pointers

I am trying to write a method that finds out if a given value exists in a linked list.

```
// Returns true if the value exists in the list.
int llist_exists(LinkedList * list, int value) {

      LinkedList *e;
      e = list->head;
      int result = 0;

      while(e != NULL)
      {
              if(e == value)
              {
                      result = 1;
                      break;
              }
      }

      return result;
```

}

Comment: And what is your question? What isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you're comparing a pointer with an int and as @xxbbcc pointed out, never moving forward in the list.
 If we assume your LinkedList class as below:

```
class LinkedList
{
public:
    int value;
    LinkedList *next;
};

int llist_exists(LinkedList * list, int value) {

      LinkedList *e;
      e = list->head;
      int result = 0;

      while(e != NULL)
      {
              if(e->value == value)
              {
                      result = 1;
                      break;
              }
              e = e->next;
      }
      return result;
}
```

Comment: OP said C, not C++. Also, your LinkedList struct doesn't have a 'head' field. But gives the general idea quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an infinite loop because you never set `e` to the next entry in the list. You need to step to the next entry in your `while` loop; something like:

```
while(e != NULL)
{
    if(e.value == value)
    {
        result = 1;
        break;
    }

    e = e->next;
}
```

Also, as [@sithereal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28818751/682404) pointed out, you're comparing `e` to the value, but `e` is an entry pointer, not the value.